# C++ dll start on a computer but not on another

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've wrote a c++ dll which aims to be injected in another process, he worked well on my computer and i wanted to try it on my second computer but when i inject it nothing happen. So I've tested with an "empty" dll with just a messagebox for showing me when the dll is injected, the dll worked on my first computer but again it doesn't work on my second computer. (nothing happen, no error, no message box)

That's the "empty" dll code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

DWORD WINAPI pInject (LPVOID param)
{
    MessageBox (0, L"Injection ok", L"ok", MB_OK);
    return 0x0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread (NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)pInject, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls (hInstance);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I've installed vc++ redistributable 2017 on both computer

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you injecting the DLL on second computer? Also is there any difference between their instruction sets(x86 vs x64?)

Comment: @ZoomIn With my own injector (i use the same injector on first and second computer) and i don't really understand your second question but both computer are running on x64 and dll compiled for x64 also

Comment: Just a thought... Do you have the same user rights on both computer? You may be administrator on the first, but not on the second...

Comment: @MartinVéronneau Thanks, I'm so stupid. Injector was not running as administrator..